# Assign groovy variable to process ID inside shell command

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh

From the pipeline, I am simple trying to set my emulators process ID to my variable *EMULATOR_PID* inside shell script like this:

```
def EMULATOR_HOME = 'C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator'
def EMULATOR_PID

pipeline {
 agent any

 stages {
    stage('Start emulator') {
        steps {
        sh "$EMULATOR_HOME/emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -port 5554 -wipe-data & $EMULATOR_PID=\$!"
      }
}
```

In the next stage I am trying to kill that process like so:

```
stage('Kill process') {
  steps {
    sh "kill $EMULATOR_PID"
}
```

When i start the build I am getting the following error output:

```
+ null=5749 <------ EMULATOR_PID
+ C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -port 5554 -wipe- 
data
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Kill processes)
[Pipeline] sh
+ kill null <------- "null" IS MY EMULATOR_PID
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/Android Test Pipeline@tmp/durable- 
d7aac378/script.sh: line 1: kill: null: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

How do I correctly assign *EMULATOR_PID* variable to my emulators process ID here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this options:

```
sPID= sh (
      script: "$EMULATOR_HOME/emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_29 -port 5554 -wipe-data & echo \$!;",
      returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
```

You may need to work a little on variable sPID to get a clean number of it

Comment: Thank you it worked, but can you explain to me how the the assignment work here?
Basically you echo the process ID like this "echo \$!" and somehow it is assigned to the variable "sPID". Does this mean you have to echo every thing you want to assign in a shell command like this one e.g?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. In this case what you are trying to achieve is read a value generated in bash, but in the pipeline you use the sh plugin as a gateway to execute bash. In that case you pipeline interacts only with the plugin, and this one with the bash script. This plugin only can return 2 things: the return status (if the script ran OK or it got an error) and capture the stdOut checkout to get anything that the script gets written on standard output. Check it on https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script